# Cannot Deploy JAX-WS webservice on Glassfish

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, glassfish-3, myeclipse

I have a problem running JAX_WS Webservices with Glassfish application server. Previously, i used to use Apache tomcat which works fine with it. But now, having Glassfish, this problem is preventing the application from being deployed... please check it below:

```
2013-04-04T13:09:23.028+0300 com.sun.xml.ws.wspolicy.com.sun.xml.ws.api.policy.ModelTranslator
SEVERE: [failed to localize] WSP_0071_ERROR_MULTIPLE_ASSERTION_CREATORS_FOR_NAMESPACE(http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing, com.sun.xml.ws.security.addressing.impl.policy.AddressingPolicyAssertionCreator, com.sun.xml.ws.addressing.impl.policy.AddressingPolicyAssertionCreator)
2013-04-04T13:09:23.028+0300 com.sun.xml.ws.wspolicy.jaxws.PolicyWSDLParserExtension
SEVERE: [failed to localize] WSP_0071_ERROR_MULTIPLE_ASSERTION_CREATORS_FOR_NAMESPACE(http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing, com.sun.xml.ws.security.addressing.impl.policy.AddressingPolicyAssertionCreator, com.sun.xml.ws.addressing.impl.policy.AddressingPolicyAssertionCreator)
2013-04-04T13:09:23.028+0300 com.sun.xml.ws.wspolicy.jaxws.PolicyWSDLParserExtension
SEVERE: WSP1007: Policy exception occurred when finishing WSDL parsing.
com.sun.xml.ws.policy.PolicyException: [failed to localize] WSP_0071_ERROR_MULTIPLE_ASSERTION_CREATORS_FOR_NAMESPACE(http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing, com.sun.xml.ws.security.addressing.impl.policy.AddressingPolicyAssertionCreator, com.sun.xml.ws.addressing.impl.policy.AddressingPolicyAssertionCreator)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.sourcemodel.PolicyModelTranslator.<init>(PolicyModelTranslator.java:188)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.policy.ModelTranslator.<init>(ModelTranslator.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.policy.ModelTranslator.<clinit>(ModelTranslator.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicies(BuilderHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicySubjects(BuilderHandler.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.doPopulate(BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.java:72)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.populate(BuilderHandler.java:82)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyMapBuilder.getNewPolicyMap(PolicyMapBuilder.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyMapBuilder.getPolicyMap(PolicyMapBuilder.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyWSDLParserExtension.postFinished(PolicyWSDLParserExtension.java:960)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.DelegatingParserExtension.postFinished(DelegatingParserExtension.java:191)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.WSDLParserExtensionFacade.postFinished(WSDLParserExtensionFacade.java:338)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:234)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:191)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:160)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:307)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:269)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:205)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:195)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:112)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:92)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.at.WSATCoordinator.<init>(WSATCoordinator.java:73)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.tx.at.ATCoordinator.<clinit>(ATCoordinator.java:1063)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:122)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:918)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:899)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:358)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferences(WebappClassLoader.java:1798)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.stop(WebappClassLoader.java:1662)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.preDestroy(WebappClassLoader.java:1631)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.getClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.getClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:450)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoOperation.run(AutoOperation.java:145)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deploy(AutoDeployer.java:575)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deployAll(AutoDeployer.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:380)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployService$1.run(AutoDeployService.java:220)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

Anybody have a idea on how to solve this error?
Please note that am using MyEclipse as my IDE with Glassfish version 3.1.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen reference to a similar problem where installing the Glassfish Web profile, instead of the full install, solves the problem. If you need the full install, this, obviously, wouldn't help.

Try exporting a war file and deploying it manually, in case there is some problem with the way MyEclipse is deploying the application.

Some servers will include some common jar files whilst others don't. So you could try adjusting what referenced jars get deployed, via the Deployment tag in the project properties under MyEclipse->Web.

I've also seen reference to the problem that is partially solved by removing a dependency on webservice-rt. I don't know if this applies to your project, but, if so, you could see if you could remove that dependency.

Comment: sorry i have no enough points to vote up for your answer..i will not forget when i will have..thx

Comment: second solution of deleting webservice-rt.jar worked for me.Thanks but can anyone please specify does metro 2.0 works with glassfish 3.1.2.2 (build 5) ?