# WAR gets deployed on Tomcat 7 but not on weblogic 12c

Tags: weblogic

My project war file gets deployed successfully on tomcat 7 but not on weblogic 12c.

While deploying a .war file on Weblogic 12c application server, I am getting the following exception:

```
<Error> <com.sun.xml.ws.wspolicy.jaxws.PolicyWSDLParserExtension> <DDC5-D-339ST4L> <myserver> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1399618140264> <BEA-000000> <WSP1007: Policy exception occurred when finishing WSDL parsing.
com.sun.xml.ws.policy.PolicyException: WSP1005: Failed to find policy referenced by URI "zip:../wls1212_dev/wls12120/user_projects/domains/mydomain/servers/myserver/tmp/_WL_user/<war name>/oiv6rb/war/WEB-INF/lib/wsit-rt-1.1.jar!/WEB-INF/wsdl/wscoor.wsdl#Addressing_policy".
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicies(BuilderHandler.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicySubjects(BuilderHandler.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.doPopulate(BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.java:72)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.populate(BuilderHandler.java:82)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyMapBuilder.getNewPolicyMap(PolicyMapBuilder.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyMapBuilder.getPolicyMap(PolicyMapBuilder.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyWSDLParserExtension.postFinished(PolicyWSDLParserExtension.java:970)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.DelegatingParserExtension.postFinished(DelegatingParserExtension.java:191)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.WSDLParserExtensionFacade.postFinished(WSDLParserExtensionFacade.java:338)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:331)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.getWSDLPort(EndpointFactory.java:746)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:254)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:577)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:560)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:639)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.getEndpoint(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:194)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:173)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:85)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.init(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:63)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:337)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:288)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:98)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:86)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:74)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:652)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:593)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1924)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1901)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1791)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2807)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:822)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:586)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

Please suggest something. Let me know in case more details are required.

Comment: Have you looked at the following? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809003/cannot-deploy-jax-ws-webservice-on-glassfish Could be a dependency on webservice-rt you need to remove. All other references to the error seem to point to glassfish and metro jars... Or lack of correct namespaces http://markmail.org/message/miy5uifuwdi4iwji